# Can I create a database to store hyperlinks to websites?

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I work with affiliate links and on occasion, my affiliates will change platforms on me.  So what I would like to create is a spreadsheet to set up hyperlinks.

Is there anyway for me to hyperlink to a google sheet cell that will redirect it to a website?

This way I am using the link to the cell on all my social media platforms and all I have to do is update the website in the cell to change my affiliate link instead of having to go through every one of my posts to update the new website link.

Comment: Your link to the google sheet cell will simply take your user to the google sheet and focus on that cell.  It may be possible to write a google script that runs when the sheet opens that launches the hyperlink in the selected cell.

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  That's the problem I was having.